# Can't click buttons that are directly under Sound/Wi-fi/Battery/Power shortcuts (top right corner)

Tags: release-freya

In example: If I open 5 tabs on chromium, I can't click on the button to open a new tab. When I use Ctrl-T to open a new tab, I can't click on it.[image: Dead area] This is the "dead" area which I can't click. It doesn't happen only in chromium, chromium was just an example. It always happens.

What could be causing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using 0.3 or 0.3.1?

Comment: I'm using 0.3.1 .

Comment: Known issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/gala/+bug/1376382

Comment: @DanielForé I have the same problem. Restart but problem persists. This is a serious problem. It happened to me for the first time yesterday. Im using  0.3.2 Freya

Comment: Happens if you miss a notification during locked PC. Not sure which timing is it, but the notification area seems frozen.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue once, then I restart my laptop and didn't experienced anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing is though, I've shut down and power on my laptop many times (not as a fix), and it didn't do anything.